# SVG - Get font-size of a TextElement

Tags: javascript, svg

How do I get the font size of a SvgTextElement when it could be set by CSS and/or inherited?

'getAttributeNS' only works if the Element has the property directly applied.
I think it may require 'baseVal' but I'm having no luck.

Browsers:
IE + Adobe Svg Viewer
Firefox
Chrome
IE9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("font-size");`

where element would be the result of document.getElementById or something similar.

Comment: Any way to do it for IE<9 with Adobe Svg Viewer?

Comment: Not that I know of. The Adobe viewer does not support getComputedStyle. You could create a hidden text element at the same point in the hierarchy, call getBBox on it and get an approximate font-size from the bounding box height.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more in the nature of a comment. The following slightly simpler formulation works:

```
var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(element).fontSize;
```

If you want to be able to search on the phrase 'font-size' then the following works:

```
var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(element)['font-size'];
```