# Increment is not working correctly in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Js is reading the `i+=2` in the for loop as

> 4002

instead of adding `2+400` which should be `402`. The increment is not in quotes so I don't know why it is doing that.

```js
function move(evt) {
  var text = evt.target;
  var currentSize = text.getAttribute("font-size");
  var timer = 0;
  for (let i = currentSize; i < 11000; i += 2) {
    function changeText() {
      text.setAttribute("font-size", i);
      console.log(i);
    }
    setTimeout((changeText), timer);
    timer = timer + 40;
  }
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 7;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg height="100%" width="100%">
            <text onclick="move(evt)" dx="0%" dy="50%" font-size="400">This is my Journey
            </text>
        </svg>
  </container>
```

Comment: `i` must be a string, not a number. Does `text.getAttribute("font-size")` return a String?

Comment: Use `var currentSize = parseInt(text.getAttribute("font-size"))` or  `var currentSize = parseFloat(text.getAttribute("font-size"))`. Kudos to @Carcigenicate.

Comment: I made a snippet but did not fix the syntax issues...

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/15195345/125981 to me here.

Comment: or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/45378743/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just as @Carcigenicate and @collapsar said on the comments; try parsing currentSize as a number.

```
  function move(evt) {
    var text = evt.target;
    var currentSize = parseInt(text.getAttribute("font-size")); // <- Parse the currentSize as int
    var timer = 0;
    for (let i = currentSize; i < 11000; i += 2) {
      function changeText() {
        text.setAttribute("font-size", 58);
        console.log(i);
      }
      setTimeout((changeText), timer);
      timer = timer + 40;
    }
  }
```